# MediaWiki pages count

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a magic word like `{{NUMBEROFARTICLES}}` for all pages?

There seem to be a discrepancy between articles and pages (Articles < Pages) and I would like to display the total number of pages.

Comment: You mean [{{NUMBEROFPAGES}}](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes, there is](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aMagic_words#Statistics):

```
{{NUMBEROFPAGES}}
```